# Ning - Wordpress Single Sign On

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, ning

I happened to chanced upon Kyle Ford's 2007 blog post regarding Wordpress' integration with Ning:
http://blog.ning.com/2007/11/wordpress_integration.html

However, the source code has been taken offline, I'm assuming it is due to the changes in the Ning API and it's transition to OAuth.

We currently have a client that would like users to login to their Ning network and automatically authenticate on their corresponding Wordpress account.  We're hosting videos on the Wordpress site that we only want users with Ning accounts to be able to access.

If you have any insight into how we can do this, any help would be appreciated.

We have complete access to the Wordpress files, but the Ning services resides on their servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing my question with the Ning developers, we found out that the capability to perform SSO with Ning -> Wordpress does not exist at this time.